# Return int word matched from List<string>

Tags: c#

Asking as a novice to get my head around this case. How would it be if I have more than one word to match. For example given another word which would match the List  of words. If I pass getvalue("paddy") should result in 100. Same goes for any word matched from List should return 100.
Thank you for your time.

```
   Console.WriteLine(getvalue("sam"));      


    public static int getvalue (string c)
    {
       //here would be creating a list
       List<string> wordlist = new List<string> { "sam", "paddy", "murphy",
                                              "saint"};
      string s;
      if(wordlist.Any(c.Contains))
      {
        s = c;
        Console.WriteLine("found word" + s);
      }
        //this should be matching the object found word
        return c == "sam" ? 100 : -10;

     }
```

Comment: return c == "sam" ? 100 : "paddy" ? 100:-10;

Comment: This question is very unclear. Maybe provide sample inputs/outputs.

Comment: @YahyaHussein close enough you got the place right where I need some better way to handle it. In case of long List would be some work to assign all in return.

Comment: As others have said its not at all clear what you are actually trying to achieve here. Do you want to just return 100 if the name is in the list and -10 otherwise? Or should sam and paddy return different values? What about things like samatha - that will tell you word is found because sam is a substring of samantha. Is this actually what you want? As Mateen says describe your requirements more clearly and sample inputs and outputs can be great for adding clarity.

Comment: @Chris point noted. Added more text to question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I understand it then you should return 100 if the check `wordlist.Any(c.Contains)` is true? If so why don't you just return 100 in that if block rather than messing around with `s`? It feels like this solution is so obvious that I must be misunderstanding something in your question still. Or is it just that what I consider obvious is less obvious to you?

Comment: Also can you confirm what "samantha" should return? Should it return 100 (because "sam" matches it) or -10 (because it doesn't appear exactly in the list)?

Comment: @Chris cheers mate , moved the return inside if block. Was trying to have something like one line return. About samantha case could be as well 100. Not looking into Substring part yet.

Comment: @khmub: you could still do it with a one line return with something like `return wordlist.Any(c.Contains)?100:-10;` but I will note that a one line return isn't always something to be aimed for. Make your code easy to understand. If that involves a single return point then great, if its easier to understand with multiple return points then don't worry about it and do that.

Comment: @Chris mate that was what I wanted just didn't had correct words to ask. Could you add that line in answer. I can mark it as solved. Have nice weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return 100 when the word or any substring of your word is in your list and -10 when it isn't then the following will work:

```
public static int getvalue (string c)
{
    List<string> wordlist = new List<string> { "sam", "paddy", "murphy", "saint"};
    return wordlist.Any(c.Contains) ? 100 : -10;
}
```

It should be noted that `c.Contains` will check if the word in the list is a substring of the input value. So The following will all return 100: samantha, sample, balsamic. If this is not what is wanted and you want exact matches only consider this:

```
public static int getvalue (string c)
{
    List<string> wordlist = new List<string> { "sam", "paddy", "murphy", "saint"};
    return wordlist.Contains(c) ? 100 : -10;
}
```

This will return 100 for sam, paddy, etc. and -10 for samantha, sample, balsamic.

I will also note that code conventions mean that you should give your parameter a better name than `c` and that the method name should be `GetValue`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like that;

```
        if (wordlist.Any(c.Contains))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found word" + s);
            return 100;
        }
        return -10;
```

Comment: ty! so i can do like return c == matchCount ? 100 : -10;

Comment: ty ! got the reply from Chris -> return wordlist.Any(c.Contains)?100:-10; I did the same as your code snippet. I will mark this as solve. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in an array or list of strings to match against, that would make it a lot simpler to check and return results.

Rainman's answer works too for the result you want.